# Getting lastInsertId from model extended by Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

Tags: zend-framework

Tried to get it that way inside extended model:

```
$this->lastInsertId();
```

and getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method InsertAd::lastInsertId()
```

Data is added successfully to the database, but i can't get auto_incremented key.

Comment: Post some code to help us help you. But first tought is are you inheriting from Zend_Db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lastInsertId is a method of the adapter.

```
$id = $this->getAdapter()->lastInsertId($stuff);
```

Comment: But in manual is written, that i can call that method from extended instance of Zend_Db_Table_Abstract.

Anyway Thanks.

Comment: @Beck well you are. $this is an instance of Zend_Db. You are using its adapter to do stuff but are still in it. Best I can come up with to explain this. Does it work for you??